gazebo harmonic - ros2 jazzy: trajectory with spurious points in rviz
I'm trying to have the gazebo harmonic/ros2 interoperability template working, a basic diff drive robot moving on a ground plane but I see spurious points in rviz2 trajectory as illustrated this screen record
I also asked the question in gazebo github there but some time they really take time to address issues/interrogation
I'm bit stuck I can not figure out why robot pose trajectory has spurious points.
Issue is not with ros bridge since a gz topic record of the trajectory shows the trajectory being wrong in gazebo side.
I think there may be interference between the 3 following plugins because commenting one of them make trajectory being good again in gazebo
      <plugin
        filename="gz-sim-joint-state-publisher-system"
        name="gz::sim::systems::JointStatePublisher">
      </plugin>

      <plugin
        filename="gz-sim-pose-publisher-system"
        name="gz::sim::systems::PosePublisher">
        <publish_link_pose>true</publish_link_pose>
        <use_pose_vector_msg>true</use_pose_vector_msg>
        <static_publisher>true</static_publisher>
        <static_update_frequency>1</static_update_frequency>
      </plugin>

      <plugin
        filename="gz-sim-odometry-publisher-system"
        name="gz::sim::systems::OdometryPublisher">
        <odom_frame>diff_drive/odom</odom_frame>
        <robot_base_frame>diff_drive</robot_base_frame>
      </plugin>

The issue seems to come from this plugin
      <plugin
        filename="gz-sim-odometry-publisher-system"
        name="gz::sim::systems::OdometryPublisher">
        <odom_frame>diff_drive/odom</odom_frame>
        <robot_base_frame>diff_drive</robot_base_frame>
      </plugin>

Ploting the trajectory with a gz topic -e -t /model/diff_drive/odometry > trajectory.txt I got those spurious points in the trajectory

While disabling the gz-sim-odometry-publisher-system in the ros_gz_project_template/ros_gz_example_gazebo/worlds/diff_drive.sdf I got a clean trajectory

